# Find a specific point on diagram (vectors) in Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I am new to Python and I want to find a specific point on my diagram.
I have vectors `I` and `V` and I want to find `V` when `I=0`.
In MATLAB, I was using interpolation:

`Voc=interp1(I,V,0)`

In Python, I tried:

`Voc=interp(0,I,V)`

But it gives me the last value of the array not at the `I=0`.

The graph is available on the following link (due to low reputation and being new in this site, I cannot post images) and I have highlighted the point that I need.

[Diagram picture](http://postimg.org/image/8jlzk4lzn/)

`V=[ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09  0.1   0.11
  0.12  0.13  0.14  0.15  0.16  0.17  0.18  0.19  0.2   0.21  0.22  0.23
  0.24  0.25  0.26  0.27  0.28  0.29  0.3   0.31  0.32  0.33  0.34  0.35
  0.36  0.37  0.38  0.39  0.4   0.41  0.42  0.43  0.44  0.45  0.46  0.47
  0.48  0.49  0.5   0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54  0.55  0.56  0.57  0.58  0.59
  0.6   0.61  0.62  0.63  0.64  0.65  0.66  0.67  0.68  0.69]`

`I= [   9.01984039    9.01984037    9.01984034    9.01984032    9.01984029
    9.01984027    9.01984024    9.01984022    9.01984019    9.01984016
    9.01984013    9.0198401     9.01984006    9.01984002    9.01983998
    9.01983992    9.01983984    9.01983974    9.01983961    9.01983942
    9.01983915    9.01983877    9.01983822    9.01983742    9.01983625
    9.01983454    9.01983202    9.01982831    9.01982286    9.01981482
    9.01980297    9.01978549    9.01975972    9.01972169    9.0196656
    9.01958284    9.01946072    9.01928054    9.01901468    9.01862239
    9.01804353    9.01718937    9.01592898    9.01406917    9.01132483
    9.00727528    9.00129976    8.99248227    8.97947117    8.96027195
    8.93194151    8.89013703    8.8284502     8.73742489    8.60310762
    8.40490856    8.1124453     7.68088544    7.04407411    6.10439296
    4.71779596    2.67172827   -0.34745683   -4.80257758  -11.37657036
  -21.07717858  -35.3914322   -56.51359815  -87.6815449  -133.67308323]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post a simple data and code example?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I added the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NumPy, as you seem to be, just do the interpolation on reversed views of the arrays to ensure `I` is increasing as `interp` requires:

```
In [5]: V0 = np.interp(0, I[::-1], V[::-1])
In [6]: V0
Out[6]: 0.6188491701618427
```

This will be much faster and save you memory if the arrays are large.

However, this will only work if your dataset is sorted (either ascending or descending order).

Comment: Thank you xnx. It is indeed shorter and Jejebelfort's solution helped me to understand it better.
Due to the low reputation, I cannot vote for you reputation but please accept my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try :

```
import numpy
V0 = numpy.interp(0, I, V)
```

Also, your data has to be sorted for interp to work correctly :

```
dataset = zip(I,V)
dataset = sorted(dataset, key=lambda data: data[0])
Isorted = [i for i,v in dataset]
Vsorted = [v for i,v in dataset]
V0 = numpy.interp(0, Isorted, Vsorted)
```

Comment: Dear Jejebelfort
I tried this code but it gives me only the last value of `V` not the interpolation result at `I=0`. I do not get your point to sort the data.

Comment: Thank you very much dear JejeBelfort. I unfortunately cannot vote for you since I do not have enough reputations. That works great and thanks again.